# The limit of the Universe that we'll ever be able to see

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion

After watching [Neil Turok's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1x9lgX8GaE&t=13m00s) at 13:00 - 13:20 he says that the Universe expands and there is a limit beyond which we will never be able to see anything.

And that's due to the Dark Matter which (as I understood) interferes with the light.

So the question is this, but please ignore the difficulties or almost-zero chance to implement (1):

Imagine we send the boundary some apparatus which is able to send a signal with the speed of light. Now, let's say we send 2 of these (you can play with induction later). Now, one stays at the boundary and sends the signals to the Earth and the second can travel further. Then suddenly we doubled the distance to that boundary, is that correct?

(1) There is [a project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakthrough_Starshot) which gives some hope or a start to hope.

Comment: *"And that's due to the Dark Matter which (as I understood) interferes with the light."* I haven't watched the video, but that's nor right. Dark matter doesn't interact with light (otherwise we'd be able to see it). I think you got confused with dark *energy* (a totally separate thing from dark matter), which causes the expansion of the universe to accelerate. That expansion limits the distance that we can ever get information from.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea would not work. Once the signal has reached a station, the station does not need to re-send the signal, because the original signal is already moving with the speed of light relative to the station. Thus the presence of the station does not increase the speed of communications.

When a distant signal reaches a station, the station would already be receding from us faster than light. When this light reaches the second station, it would happen farther away from us compared to the first station, because of the expansion of space. The [particle horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_horizon) cannot be penetrated.

Please note that we can see light from galaxies receding from us faster than light: "*3.3 Misconception #3: Galaxies with recession velocities exceeding the speed of light exist but we cannot see them*" - [Expanding Confusion](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0310808).

Please also note that the existence of the particle horizon depends on the cosmological model of choice. There is no experimental evidence of the particle horizon or of the fact that not all universe is observable. These are theoretical predictions of the Lambda-CDM cosmological model that is widely accepted by physicists due to its correct predictions in other areas.

Comment: FWIW, here's a popular article on expansion by Davis & Lineweaver which is a lot easier to read than their classic Expanding Confusion paper: https://people.smp.uq.edu.au/TamaraDavis/papers/SciAm_BigBang.pdf

Comment: @PM2Ring Excellent reference for this question. Thanks so much!

Comment: @safesphere please note that the suggested solution would not try to solve the speed of the signal but rather the limit of the signal lost due to the dark energy as Qmechanic correctly pointed. So imagine that between each two stations the signal won't be lost. That's the only purpose. WDYT?

Comment: @valk Sure, you can amplify the signal in transit and, with a persistent acceleration, your probes can reach super luminal speeds at a large distance relative to the origin (but never outrun a ray of light). Eventually your probes can even cross the boundary of our observable universe and disappear from our view forever. None of this would help you to get any information from beyond the horizon, because, again, the presence of the probes does not increase the speed of the signal. If light is not fast enough to cross back the moving boundary, then nothing can help you get this information.

Answer (score 1):

It is not directly because of dark energy (he said dark energy, not matter), it is because of the accelerating expansion of the universe, which is believed to be caused by dark energy. The distance between opposite sides of the universe is increasing faster than the speed of light, so the light can never reach the other side. Any space crafts sent out would not go as fast as light, so they would never reach the other side either. As a result of this, once we look far enough away into the universe, objects will be red shifted because they seem to be moving away from us (objects are not actually "moving" away, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_of_the_universe ) If we look farther still we will eventually not be able to see what is "expanding away" from us faster than light.

Comment: Faster-than-light expansion doesn’t necessarily imply that you cannot communicate. We easily see galaxies that recede faster than the speed of light, and also did when they emitted the light we see.

Comment: @peta: so will we always see the entire universe, and have communication?

Comment: @safesphere:  " Light that is emitted today from galaxies beyond the cosmological event horizon, about 5 gigaparsecs or 16 billion light-years, will never reach us"  quote from Wikipedia  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_of_the_universe

Comment: A link to (at least some of) what Pela's talking about is  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32374/is-the-universe-older-than-13-7-billion-years/32402

Comment: Are there any galaxies 16 billion light years from us? I thought that at 13.8 light years all we could see was the CMB.

Comment: Just purely theoretical engineering: let's say we throw 200 stations into the space, each one is 2x speed of the previous one. So it's like an accordion. The first one (we are in theory here) ha speed of 16 bln light years. And suppose that's the same speed the stations can communicate (yes crazy, but for the simplicity). That means that after 2 years we could receive the signal from the second station right? Now I know there are many ifs and this is impossible to achieve but is the model correct? In other words, if we will ever be able to reach the limit, it won't be the limit of knowledge?

Comment: 14 Gly seems more in line with the currently accepted age of the universe, but I wouldn't be surprised if that needed to be revised eventually, when astronomers and cosmologists have more data. I'd have thought that the further expansion whle the light from the early universe was on its way to us would have been included in the redshift that we observe.

Comment: There have also been suggestions of "tired light". It seems possible that there is something which slows light down which we don't know about or haven't considered. For example, space isn''t a perfect vacuum, and that was even more true when it was more compressed.